# SQL Server Query COUNT NULL/Blank Values and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, rest

I have been trying to figure this out without success. I have a table called `Appraisal` which has a column `StatusID`. I need to count the number of appraisals grouped by `StatusId`. Some records in `Appraisal` have NULL/blank values in the `StatusID`. The end result would be to return 0 if an appraiser has appraisal with `StatusId = NULL`.

**Appraisal**

```
[AppraisalId] [AppraiserId] [StatusId]
1           11111           1
2           11111           2
3           11111           NULL
4           22222           4
5           22222           NULL
...
```

**AppraisalStatus**

```
[AppraisalStatusId] [AppraisalStatusName]
2                   Assigned
3                   Accepted
6                   Conditionally Declined
7                   Completed
10                  On Hold
11                  Order Not Accepted
```

**Appraiser**

```
[AppraiserId]
11111
22222
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    AppraisalStatus.AppraisalStatusId, 
    COUNT(ISNULL(Appraisal.StatusId, 0)) AS "number_of_orders"
FROM
    AppraisalStatus
LEFT JOIN 
    Appraisal ON AppraisalStatus.AppraisalStatusId = Appraisal.StatusId
WHERE 
    AppraiserId = :AppraiserId
```

The results in JSON

```
[{
  "AppraisalStatusId": 2,
  "number_of_orders": 1
}, {
  "AppraisalStatusId": 3,
  "number_of_orders": 5
}, {
  "AppraisalStatusId": 7,
  "number_of_orders": 184
}, {
  "AppraisalStatusId": 10,
  "number_of_orders": 2
}]
```

Comment: are you missing a GROUP BY somewhere?

Comment: not sure, i have read some many explanations. I just cant get the query to return  "AppraisalStatusId": 6,
  "number_of_orders": 0

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you intend?

```
SELECT aps.AppraisalStatusId, COUNT(a.StatusId) as number_of_orders
FROM AppraisalStatus aps LEFT JOIN
     Appraisal a
     ON aps.AppraisalStatusId = a.StatusId AND
        a.AppraiserId = :AppraiserId
GROUP BY aps.AppraisalStatusId;
```

This will return one row for each status for the given Appraiser.  If there are no matching records then the value is 0.

Comment: How does this differ from what you want?

Comment: First error: message: The multi-part identifier "ap.AppraiserId" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    AppraisalStatus.AppraisalStatusId, 
    SUM(IIF(Appraisal.StatusId IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS "number_of_orders"
FROM
    AppraisalStatus
LEFT JOIN 
    Appraisal ON AppraisalStatus.AppraisalStatusId = Appraisal.StatusId
WHERE 
    AppraiserId = :AppraiserId
GROUP BY AppraisalStatus.AppraisalStatusId
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, much appreciated. I am getting error message "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'". Upon further investigation, IIF isn't a valid function in SQL 2008, which is the version of the database. Though not sure why its complaining about IS

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012, I am not sure SQL Server 2008 does support `IIF` or not. You can also use CASE statement instead of IIF.